# Is the length of DFA's input is finite?

Tags: dfa

If it is, for some DFA, I think the language it recognizes includes some string whose length is infinite;
If not, will it never stop when the input is a infinite string.

This is confusing to me.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it does make you confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Each input is finite, though there may be no upper bound on the input length.

For example, consider `a*`. This may be the empty string, `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc.

The length of each input is finite, though there is no upper bound on the length.

FYI, the *number of possible inputs* (as opposed to the length of an input) can be infinite. It's just like there being an infinite number of finite integers.

Comment: Thank you. But is the following case possible? There is an input string whose length is infinite. We don't know which state it will stop at. So we don't know finally it will be accepted or rejected.

Comment: Am I misunderstand something? Forgive my poor knowledge please.

Comment: @Quimby, no. As normally defined, a DFA has *finite* input.